# Is there any way to wrap a cell in plotly?

Tags: python, plotly, cell, center

Is there any way to wrap a cell (to long text fit in my cell), and also to place them in center? 
This is my table:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Table(
    header=dict(values=['','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','thursday','friday','saturday','sunday'],
                line_color='darkslategray',
                fill_color='lightgray',
                align='center'),
     cells=dict(values=[['asdasdasd', 'xvxdwefsdf','asdadwq','zxvwefqewf','wqe124qs'],
                        ["res", 'ds', 'ob', 'pww', 'kw'], # 1 column
                        ['res1', 'ds1', 'ob1', 'pww1', 'kw1'],# 2 column
                        ['res2', 'ds2', 'ob2qweqweqweqweqweqew', 'pww2', 'kw2'],# 3 column
                        ['res3', 'ds3', 'ob4', 'pww3', 'kw3'],# 4 column
                        ['res4', 'ds4', 'ob5', 'pw14151222231231dvzv3123123w4', 'kw4'],# 5 column
                        ['Pancakes' , 'ds5', 'ob6',  'pww5', 'kw5'] ,# 6 column
                        ['Jajecznica', 'ds6', 'obnd' , 'pww6' ,'kw6']], # 7 column
               line_color='darkslategray',
               fill_color='white',
               align='center', 
               height=60))
])
values=['asdasdasd', 'xvxdwefsdf','asdadwq','zxvwefqewf','wqe124qs']
fig.update_layout(width=1300, height=700)

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The answer:**

Long *sentences* are not a  problem, but long *words* can be.

**The details:**

This is a good question. And had me *really* confused for a while. Because by the looks of some of the examples, Plotly wraps [long strings in cells](https://plotly.com/python/table/#tables-with-graphs) really well:

[image]

But this happens *between* words, identified by a `space`. So in the referred example, if you remove the spaces, you'd get:

[image]

So what you should do with your real life example is to plan the design and content of your `go.Table` carefully. And if you have to split a long word, you can of course use a [html line break](https://www.teachucomp.com/add-a-line-break-in-html-tutorial/) instead of `space` to get this:

[image]

In your code snippet, just replace

```
'ob2qweqweqweqweqweqew',
```

...with:

```
'ob2qweqweq<br>weqweqweqew'
```